# Is it possible to combine Hydrogen with Shopify Themes?

Tags: shopify

I've two question on how to use Hydrogen, would be awesome if someone can answer it.

1. The customer wants a new landing page but with the old theme/shop, is it possible to combine Hydrogen with the old Shopify theme?
2. Let's say im creating a shop for a customer with Hydrogen. Can the customer adjust the store (Not just products but also for e.g.: different headers, texts, menus... just like in the previous version with Shopify themes)?

Thank you for your time

Emil

Answer (score 0):

1. *Kind of*. Hydrogen can proxy selected urls to the Liquid store. For example, you could create a route for `/products/<handle>` which fetches the product page from the traditional Online Store.
2. You'd need to build the functionality for them by reading [products](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2021-07/queries/products), [menu](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2021-07/queries/menu), etc. There's also a [Hydrogen Sanity CMS plugin](https://github.com/sanity-io/hydrogen-plugin-sanity) which might help!

Comment: Based on https://shopify.github.io/hydrogen-v1/tutorials/proxy-routes-to-online-store, proxying is only available on Oxygen and user sessions can't be shared. Those are pretty big limitations.